# Is my Interpretation of this statistical distribution correct?

Tags: statistical-significance, normal-distribution, standard-deviation

[image]

The torque of shld flx action was between 8Nm to 10NM for 10% of the time
Is my interpretation correct?  If so how do I determine torque for one of the 19 activities?

Comment: It's not clear what your last question means. What do you mean by "determine torque" ... the torque measurement apparently varies from measurement instance to measurement instance. What is it you want to find out?

Comment: It is stated  that the torque was measured for 19 different daily activities .Am I right to say that each bar in the histogram represents one of the activity? how to find out torque for a specific activity . I hope I understood well.

Comment: If I take a large number of people and measure their height, I could do a histogram of all the heights. Your question corresponds to looking at the histogram and asking "how do I find out the height?" ... which one? it was measured a bunch of times -- if there was just one height it wouldn't be a histogram. So "how do I determine the torque of an activity" doesn't make sense to me here, unless you define the "torque of an activity" in terms of a collection of values... in that case you must give *us* the definition of "the torque of an activity".

Comment: I will describe the experimental setup in detail. There are 7 different joints in the hand. Each joint can be moved in 2 ways for example supination and pronation is for the joint in the wrist. The subject has been asked to do 19 different activities  e.g. Grab a cup, to measure the torque at each joint. Each activity has been repeatedly performed to get a bunch of  torque values for each joint. I am not sure how to find out torque for a specific activity at specific joint?

Comment: Exactly! You say "Each activity has been repeatedly performed to get a bunch of torque values". The diagram shows *every* such value. it displays a large quantity of torque values. You're now asking for *one* such value. (As if I have a basket of oranges and you're saying "can I have *the* orange?" as if I only had one. Which orange did you mean?) So I say again, which *one* do you want? If you want some kind of summary of all values you'll have to explain what summary you want.

Comment: Oh! Each bin represents torque values of all the activities. I was been misinterpreting as each bar actually represents the torque value of a single activity which I believe is wrong. So I can only get summary of how many times a range of torque value  was been recorded when performing all of the activities. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, the height of each block represents the proportion (more often the raw count, but in this case it's scaled to a proportion) of measurements falling into that torque-bin - that's what a histogram does. However, strictly speaking, the display is faulty -- there should not be gaps between adjacent bins in a histogram, since it implies a small interval between each pair of adjacent bins into which no values will fall. I now see that what you needed explained was more like "what is a histogram?"; my apologies -- I'll add something along those lines.

Answer (score 1):

Let's begin by looking at what a histogram is.

The basic histogram is a representation of the observed distribution of some variable, obtained by splitting the observed range into a set of mutually exclusive, exhaustive bins (usually of equal width):

[image]

Here the red ticks mark bin-boundaries (the black ticks are for the axis-labels)

Then fixed-height little rectangular boxes the same width as the corresponding bin - one per observation in that bin - are stacked up, so that the height of the bar that results represents the count (or, sometimes, the proportion) in the bin.

e.g. see Wikipedia's entry on the [histogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram).

Looking in detail at your histogram:

[image]

We can see that the left ends of the boxes don't consistently line up at a fixed distance from the integers on the tick marks - the bin boundaries can't occur at round numbers, since the boxes start further to the left as you move to smaller numbers (looking at the boxes on the left, like near "-2", they don't really line up as they do near 10).

The vertical green lines are at 7.5 and 10.5 (obtained by counting pixels); part of the box (nearly) centered at 8 sticks out.

Similarly, the estimated percentages for each of the indicated boxes was obtained by counting pixels compared to the y-axis.

In each case there can be some inaccuracy; those values I labelled the bars with could easily be out half of one percent or more.